# How to format decimal as a string with defined precision using printf/sprintf in F#?

Tags: string, f#, format, printf, decimal

I want to format decimal value as string with a defined precision in F#. While using printf/sprintf I get:

```
let sdecimal = sprintf "%.2M" 0.1234M;;
```

> val sdecimal : string = "0.1234"

while for float it works.

```
let sfloat = sprintf "%.2f" 0.1234;;
```

> val sfloat : string = "0.12"

Seems like I have to first cast it to float which is both verbose and non-kosher.

Is there a simpler way than using C#'s .ToString() formatting?

Comment: use the same format as for float: `sprintf "%.2f" 0.1234M;;`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK. It works if the formatting is for float:

```
let sfdecimal = sprintf "%.2f" 0.1234M;;
```

> val sfdecimal : string = "0.12"

The type information is still preserved as pointed out in the comments by @[scrwtp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/679898/scrwtp).

Comment: This is not strictly speaking true - format specifiers are still typechecked, it's just that the mapping isn't one-to-one. `%f` matches any floating point type (`Single`, `Double`, `Decimal`) but not `int` etc. `String.Format` ignores type information.